# Is Wayne's World's (NOT) a modern invention?

Tags: meaning-in-context, abbreviations, syntactic-analysis, conversation

Older users of this site may recall the <strike>'Bill & Ted'</strike> 'Wayne's World' series of movies of the early 1990s. They were mindless but fairly amusing and their eponymous characters spoke in a unique vernacular, part-stoner, part-surfer, part-moronic generation MTVer. One of the features of this sub-language was the use of the word 'Not' *usually written as* **(NOT)**, a convention which served to negate the content or validity of what had been said previously.

E.g.

```
"I think your wife is very attractive. (NOT)"
```

or

```
"I love your new hairstyle. (NOT)"
```

Does anyone know if this usage is a modern invention or whether there are antecedents in ancient or more recent languages which are similarly employed to, wittily or otherwise, invalidate previous statements spoken? I'm not necessarily looking for usages of 'not' itself, but any similar linguistic devices.

Comment: This is not from Bill and Ted, it's from Waynes World

Comment: hints to search: At that particular time, the Saturday Night Live skit 'Wayne's World' had become a movie, and was famous for pointedly using the single 'not' construction. I don't remember at the time the Bill and Ted movies (the first one was out in 1989 and WW in 1992) so a confirming quote from either would help. But of course people forget the prior SNL skit from the 70's where Steve Martin used the construction. Before that...I don't have any ideas.

Comment: I seem to remember it wasn't uncommon to append "**, I don't think!**" as a jocular negating addendum, as far back as the 60s. You often hear "**Nah! - Just kidding!**" used today to the same effect. But I must admit that **(NOT)** has overtones of "baby-talk" to me.

Comment: Argh - I think I've just publicly had my first 'senior moment' - of course it was Wayne's World. Yours sheepishly etc., etc.

Comment: I've seen the usage in one of Rex Stout's Nero Wolfe mysteries (though I don't remember which, offhand), which date from the '30s to mid-70s.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Oxford English Dictionary includes this form of *not* as an interjection, writing:

> *colloq.* [perhaps influenced by nit adv. (see J. T. Sheidlower and J. E. Lighter in Amer. Speech (1993) 68 213–8). In later use, popularized by Mike Myers and Dana Carvey in the ‘Wayne's World’ sketches on the NBC television programme Saturday Night Live from 1989, and especially by the spin-off film Wayne's World in 1992.] Used humorously following a statement to indicate that it should not be taken seriously (usually because the idea expressed is untrue or unlikely to happen), or sarcastically to negate a statement made immediately before.

There are actually uses of this in the 1800s:

> [1860    ‘G. Eliot’ Mill on Floss III. vi. vi. 90   She would make a sweet, strange, troublesome, adorable wife to some man or other, but he would never have chosen her himself. Did she feel as he did? He hoped she did—not.]
>
> 1888    Cincinnati Times-Star 26 July 2/2   Of course ‘White Wings’ was mourned because he was hissed. Yes he did—not!!!
>
> 1893    Princeton Tiger 30 Mar. 103   An Historical Parallel—Not.

After these uses, *Wayne's World* popularized the phrase in the late 20th century.

Comment: The 1800s usage is distinctly different, insofar as it involves a simple pause in timing before completing the negation of the verb.  In Wayne's World, the entire sentence was completed, and the negation happened separately from the verb, so the entire sentence was negated.

Comment: The Princeton Tiger (whatever that is) example is no different as I see it.

Comment: @z7sgѪ: The [Princeton Tiger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Princeton_Tiger_Magazine) is a humor magazine written by Princeton University students.

Comment: What does "nit adv." mean in the OED quote?

Comment: Archie Goodwin, the narrator of the Nero Wolfe novels, uses "not" in this way a couple of times.

Comment: @hippietrail - you mis-parsed that. "Perhaps influenced by nit" and "adv." do not go together. This use of "not" may be related to the word "not." And "not" is an adverb.

Comment: @JamesMcLeod: I think you're right and I was thrown because "nit" looks like an abbreviation and as a word I only know it to mean "louse egg" and not something I can relate to "not".

Comment: @hippietrail actually they *do* go together... "nit adv." means "the entry for the word 'nit' as an adverb", which does exist in OED. It's a synonym for "not", first citation 1894, last citation 1942, and a note of "frequently used humorously or ironically following a statement to indicate that it should not be believed or taken seriously."

Answer (score 3):

In defense of 5arx's initial association of the interjection "not!" with the *Bill & Ted* comedy franchise, I note this chronological listing in J.E. Lighter, *Random House Dictionary of Historical American Slang* (1997):

> **1991** *Bill & Ted's Adventures* (CBS-TV): Smooth move, dude! Not! **1992** M. Myers et al. *Wayne's World* (film): Wayne'll understand that right away. Not!

Still, as simchona points out, *Wayne's World* is generally credited with the resurgence in popularity of the usage—which in any case is more than 100 years old. In addition to the *Princeton Tiger* instance that simchona cites, Lighter notes such modern-sounding instances as these two:

> **1905** E.P. Butler, in *Amer. Magazine* (Sept.) 499: Cert'nly, me dear frind, Flannery. Delighted. *Not!* **1908** in Canemaker *W. McCay* 75: That confounded rarebit I ate...is making me sleep lovely. NOT!!!

You can confirm Lighter's findings in the Google Books entries for Ellis Butler's short story "[Pigs Is Pigs](https://books.google.com/books?id=gNcXAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA499&dq=%22Flannery.+Delighted.+Not%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiA6OnFwsXKAhVN-2MKHfQvCboQ6AEIITAB#v=onepage&q=%22Flannery.%20Delighted.%20Not%22&f=false)" and for Mark Dunn, [Zounds!: A Browser's Dictionary of Interjections](https://books.google.com/books?id=0mmxYyOwVt8C&pg=PA120&dq=%22sleep+lovely+Not%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwid-4myw8XKAhVW92MKHQDaD2EQ6AEIIjAB#v=onepage&q=%22sleep%20lovely%20Not%22&f=false) (2005). Besides identifying the 1908 example as being from a Winsor McCay cartoon (presumably part of the *Dream of the Rarebit Fiend* series), Dunn points to an even earlier instance, by George Ade, that uses *not* similarly. From George Ade, "[The Fable of What Happened the Night the Men Came to the Women's Club](https://books.google.com/books?id=oz8qAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA80&dq=%22front+room+and+hear+some+more%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjo-LeixsXKAhUD42MKHS9xDD8Q6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=%22front%20room%20and%20hear%20some%20more%22&f=false)," in *More Fables in Slang* (1900):

> Now Josephine was right there to see that Everybody had a Nice Time, and she did not like to see the Prominent Business Men of the Town dying of Thirst or Leg Cramp or anything like that, so she gave two or three of them the Quiet Wink, and they tiptoed after her out to the Dining Room, where she offered Refreshments, and said they could slip out on the Side Porch and Smoke if they wanted to.
>
> Probably they preferred to go back in the Front Room and hear some more about Woman's Destiny **not**.

Another fairly early instance appears in Shirley Seifert, "[The Nicest Boy and What the Smartest Girl in the Office Did to Him](https://books.google.com/books?id=U5xJAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA79&dq=%22how+polite+you+are%E2%80%94not+said+Kitty%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj8lI6sh57gAhWN458KHWEICKQQ6AEIKjAA#v=onepage&q=%22how%20polite%20you%20are%E2%80%94not%20said%20Kitty%22&f=false)," in *The Delineator* (July-August 1920):

> "Isn't it a cold night?" she [Kitty] said snippily to the gloomy, immaculate young man who called for her at eight the night of the party.
>
> "So-so," said Benny, not committing himself.
>
> "I think it's very warm myself," she said five minutes later.
>
> "You just said it was cold," the young man reminded her. "Don't you know your own mind?"
>
> "My, how polite you are—***not!***" said Kitty.

Comment: Thank you for the validation. I *knew* I'd heard those two say it, albeit the intervening three decades may have fogged the memory somewhat.

Answer (score 2):

No. I used to hear it in a somewhat [simliar teenager-themed skit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Nerds) on SNL with its first cast back in the late '70's. (Gilda Radner played "Lisa Loopner" and Bill Murray played a nerdy boy named "Todd").