# Writing the most important part of a sentence (at the end, between parentheses)

Tags: writing-style, parentheses

I've seen this writing style several times, where the most important part of a sentence - or a twist - is put at the end between parentheses. This is typically used in titles and gives the sentence an ironic or cynical tone.

Examples:

> The new ways to lose weight (that don't work)
>
> The car of your dreams exists (but you'll never have it)
>
> A simple recipe for happiness (that nobody follows)

Does this writing style have a name? Which prominent author used it first, if any?

Comment: related :[is-waynes-worlds-not-a-modern-invention](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/40774/is-waynes-worlds-not-a-modern-invention)

Comment: Please, oh please, add the Wayne's World "(not)" to the list of examples.

Comment: I would call this a conscious destruction of irony, subtlety, and nuance. People who practice it are masters of the *single entendre*.

Comment: I find the parentheses superfluous (or perhaps simply wrong).

Comment: I would call these *cracked headlines* in that they are extremely popular on the site Cracked.com and generally only found there or in online advertisements and tabloids.
Examples from the last week:
"6 Terrifying Sci-Fi Predictions (About the Year 1997)" 
"5 Common Responses to Awkwardness (That Make Things Worse)"

Answer (score 6):

The rhetorical device of *Paraprosdokian* may be what you're looking for - it refers to a surprise or unexpected ending of a phrase or series.

> *He was at his best when the going was good. (Alistair Cooke on the
>   Duke of Windsor)