# An expression regarding "wanting means to become able to"

Tags: expressions

There is a philosophical proverb in Persian that says:

خواستن توانستن است

It literally means "To want is to be able to"

And it promotes the ethics of doing one's best and trying.

It encourages people to want things and to do what they can to enhance their capabilities in order to fullfil that want.

Is there an equivalent philosophical proverb/expression/idiom in English for this purpose? Because it seems that it's very universal and I expect English to have something similar.

Comment: Closely related: [Meaning of 'Where will wants not, a way opens'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/123444/meaning-of-where-will-wants-not-a-way-opens/123446#123446) (Tolkien).

Answer (score 3):

"Where there's a will, there's a way" (Proverb)

> *idiom*, used to mean that if you are determined enough, you can find a way to achieve what you want, even if it is very difficult ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/where-there-s-a-will-there-s-a-way))

"Do or do not -- there is no try" (Yoda from Star wars)

> Either you do something or you don’t; trying (and failing) doesn't count. [One] must have an extraordinary amount of self-confidence in order to achieve the improbable. ([EarnestAssoc.com](https://earnestassoc.com/2015/12/16/do-or-do-not-there-is-no-try/#:%7E:text=Encouraging%20Luke%20Skywalker%20to%20fully,order%20to%20achieve%20the%20improbable.))

"You can get it if you really want it" (Ska song -- Desmond Dekker)

> If you really want something-truly and fully- it's possible to achieve it and fulfill your desire.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: "Where there's a will, there's a way" turns up in several dictionaries. You could find a reference and explain exactly what it means, because it certainly fits the question.

Answer (score 3):

*Merriam-Webster* has this idiom

**Necessity is the mother of invention**

> used to say that new ways to do things are found or created when there is a strong and special need for them