# How do you say "make a stack from a pile of sheets of paper" in one word?

Tags: single-word-requests

*Fold* a pile of papers into a stack? *NOT*.
Is there a word that expresses this concept?

Comment: You probably want *straighten*. What on earth is "Nooot"?

Comment: @AndrewLeach This should explain it, mostly: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/40774/is-waynes-worlds-not-a-modern-invention/

Comment: Understand that "u" may be considered offensive enough on ELU to attract downvotes just for being so tacky/rude/disrespectful/negligent.

Comment: NOOOT the only definition in English I found (UrbanDict) When two busy people, walking in opposite directions meet in a hallway or tight corridor and annoyingly step out of the way of the other but the other steps in the same direction. After happening several times, the awkwardness is averted when one stops moving and the other passes.

Comment: NOOOT is NOT but with two extra Os so I can f!&*K with all of you literature people. :)

Answer (score 4):

More concisely, you could say "stack some papers."

On the usage of "stack" as a verb:

> verb (used with object)
>
> to pile, arrange, or place in a stack: to stack hay; to stack rifles.

From dictionary.com

Comment: This is the answer. Stack those papers.

Answer (score 2):

This may be more specific than what you're looking for, but a possibility is:

**collate**:

> 2) To assemble in proper numerical and logical sequence
>  3)
>   *Printing* a) To examine (gathered sheets) in order to arrange them in sequence before binding.

(AHD, 4th edition)

---

> 3) To sort multiple copies of printed documents into sequences of
>   individual page order, one sequence for each copy, especially before
>   binding.

([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/collate))

Answer (score 1):

You could say that you have **tidied** the pile

> **tidy**
>  verb
>   1. bring order to; arrange neatly.

([Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=tidy%20definition))

Answer (score 0):

***Organize*** ([Oxf](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/organize?q=organise)) a pile of papers into a neat stack.

Comment: RK01 please add quotations references and definitions to avoid woolly thinking which otherwise swamps the site.